# How to run X Windows from a (headless) Ubuntu server?

Tags: java, ubuntu, virtual-machine, jvisualvm, x11

We have an Ubuntu server VM that is running a Java application on it, and I need to profile it using Java's [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) GUI tool.

I need to SSH into the server (say, `ssh admin@ourapp.example.com`) and turn on X Windows so that I can run JVisualVM at the terminal and have the X Window "break out" of the VM and run on my host (a Windows 7 machine).

Comment: Use `cygwin` and `Xorg` to start a server on your Windows machine, then use cygwin's xterm and `ssh -Y` to enable X11 forwarding. Make sure you install X and ssh when you install cygwin.

Comment: Much easier: Use Xmingw and PuTTY.

Comment: How to we use Xmingw and PuTTY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps :

1. Install X-Windows on your Windows 7 machine (example exceed or Xming)
2. ssh to your unix machine
3. export DISPLAY to the ip address of you Win 7 box
    export DISPLAY=10.10.20.30:0.0
4. Test it by running xterm or JVisualVM

Comment: it didn't work for me :( I get display not found error even though the ip is correct